# Spring Kafka and exactly once delivery guarantee

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use Spring Kafka and Spring Boot and just wondering how to configure my consumer, for example:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.post.send}", containerFactory = "postKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void sendPost(ConsumerRecord<String, Post> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack) {

    // do some logic

    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

to use the exactly once delivery guarantee?

Should I only add `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation over `sendPost` method and that's it or do I need to perform some extra steps in order to achieve this?

**UPDATED**

This is my current config

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties, KafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> transactionManager) {

        kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerMaxPollIntervalMs);
        kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerMaxPollRecords);

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        //factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(kafkaProperties));

        return factory;
    }


    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 15000000);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Post> postProducerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Post> postKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(postProducerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Update> updateProducerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Update> updateKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(updateProducerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Message> messageProducerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Message> messageKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(messageProducerFactory());
    }
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method kafkaTransactionManager in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 3 were found:
    - postProducerFactory: defined by method 'postProducerFactory' in class path resource [com/example/domain/configuration/messaging/KafkaProducerConfig.class]
    - updateProducerFactory: defined by method 'updateProducerFactory' in class path resource [com/example/domain/configuration/messaging/KafkaProducerConfig.class]
    - messageProducerFactory: defined by method 'messageProducerFactory' in class path resource [com/example/domain/configuration/messaging/KafkaProducerConfig.class]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use manual acknowledgments. Instead, inject a `KafkaTransactionManager` into the listener container and the container will send the offset to the transaction when the listener method exits normally (or rollback otherwise).

You should not do acks via the consumer for exactly once.

**EDIT**

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      enable-auto-commit: false
      properties:
        isolation:
          level: read_committed
    producer:
      transaction-id-prefix: myTrans.
```

**App**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So52570118Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So52570118Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean // override boot's auto-config to add txm
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            KafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> transactionManager) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return factory;
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @KafkaListener(id = "so52570118", topics = "so52570118")
    public void listen(String in) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(in);
        Thread.sleep(5_000);
        this.template.send("so52570118out", in.toUpperCase());
        System.out.println("sent");
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so52570118out", topics = "so52570118out")
    public void listenOut(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> this.template.executeInTransaction(t -> t.send("so52570118", "foo"));
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return new NewTopic("so52570118", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return new NewTopic("so52570118out", 1, (short) 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please show an example of how to use `KafkaTransactionManager` with Spring Boot?

Comment: Actually, you don't need a transaction manager bean, boot auto-configures one (edited).

Comment: Thanks! I updated my configuration but it fails with the error. I have updated my question. What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Since you are defining your own producer factories (and more than one), one of them (the one you want the transactions to run for) needs to be marked `@Primary` - or you can explicitly define your own transaction manager `@Bean` instead of using Boots auto-configured one.

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to run transactions for all of them?

Comment: How to configure in this case?

Comment: Given that you are using the same producerConfigs for each, why not just create one with `<String, Object>`? You would have to do that if you want sends from each template to participate in the same transaction, since the transaction is scoped at the producer.